# How do I prevent my navbar from turning into a dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I created a new project, and chose the MVC model, and most pleasingly, I was greeted by this auto-generated site by Microsoft

[image: When it works]

I made a simple change in the code, trying to render an html header (a simple greeting), including the text value from a custom-made object, like so:

Making the property in the HomeController
[image: Viewbag]

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        ViewBag.NewProperty = "This is my first app!";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Accessing the same property from my View
[image: Viewbag.NewProperty]

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
<h1>@ViewBag.NewProperty</h1>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

But as you can probably imagine, I was instead bewildered by what was then presented before me as I re-launched my web application

[image: this error]

I had of course been expecting to see my previous view, but with my new H1 property added unto the page.
Instead I was baffled at how I managed to be so clumsy, as to fail such a simple task.

Therefore, I sincerely plead, that the professional community here on Stackoverflow can help shed some light on what is going wrong.

I haven't changed the code in any shape or form besides what I have now shared with you.

Comment: Can you post the actual code and not just screenshots, please...?
It is difficult to diagnose issues when you have to type in all that code too...

Comment: is this bootstrap?

Comment: Hello Any

Thank you for your response.

I have corrected my mistake, and added code blocks beneath the screenshots, as requested.

I apologize for any inconvenience

Brad Bit

Comment: Hello Daniel

Yes, you are correct. I am using bootstrap in this application

Brad Bit

Answer (score 4):

It's a BootStrap problem. Go to your Nuget manager and uninstall your bootstrap, then reinstall BootStrap version 3.3.7. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this question, Gozzah! 
Everything works now as it should. 
I am glad that it wasn't a more complicated issue, and that you were so fast to solve the issue.

All the best

- Brad Bit